# C# MVC dropdown for selecting Hours must have leading zero, how to do this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdown

Hours are numbers without zeroes, but dropdown must show 01,02 etc.
Here what I have..... Thanks.

```
<td>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Spots[i].AirTimeHr, new SelectList(ViewBag.Hours, "Value", "Text", Model.Spots[i].AirTimeHr), new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 65px;" })                        
</td>
```

Comment: For view only you need to display with zero?

Comment: Show how your generating your `SelectList` (i.e. `ViewBag.Hours`). All you need to do is format the `Text` property of `SelectListItem`

Comment: Yes. I am having difficulties with generating SelectList.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a view model, I'd just create another C# property that returns the list as strings (a dictionary with int keys and string values to be returned for example), with the needed massaging done (adding leading zero to single letter strings).

Comment: displaymin.Add(new DisplayTime() { Text = "  ", Value = 99 }); displaymin.Add(new DisplayTime() { Text = "00", Value = 0 });

Comment: Obviously I don't want to have Value = 99. 0 is used and it is a valid number. So, what should go where Text = " ".

Comment: Can you explain again? If you mean adding zero only when needed, you can decide that based on length of the number (if the string is one letter == one digit, you prefix it with "0"). Is that what you mean or something else?